# Panzer Corps, Stalingrad - a loss with victory conditions satisfied

Tags: panzer-corps

I'm playing Panzer Corps campaign. For Stalingrad, "marginal victory" condition is to capture all objectives except three cities in Caucasus. I captured all objectives except Baku (furthest to the south) and got loss. This seems to be a bug.

Maybe it has something to do with capturing some cities with Romanian units, but on strategic map they still show as mine (grey).

So, why?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in this scenario. However, in this case it does not matter. Whatever the result you always get send to Kursk after the battle, and you will always get 2880 prestige.

Source: [Matrix games forums](http://www.matrixgames.com/forums/tm.asp?m=2874875&mpage=1&key=&#2878681)